# How to plot machine learning model horizontally?

Tags: plot, keras

I want to draw a machine learning model.
In some paper, they draw models horizontally like Figure 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 in https://tches.iacr.org/index.php/TCHES/article/view/7388/6560.
These seems to have drawn models from keras.
How can I do like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use this example:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation

model = Sequential([
    Dense(32, input_shape=(784,)),
    Activation('relu'),
    Dense(10),
    Activation('softmax'),
])

from keras.utils import plot_model
plot_model(model,
           show_shapes=True,
           to_file='model.png'
)
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: I can draw like that, but I wonder how to draw using multi columns

Answer (score 1):

I think the paper you cited just generated their model plots in Keras in one large column, and then cut them out and add the curved arrows in a 2D software (Gimp, Photoshop).

Answer (score 1):

If you change the default hyperparameter
`rankdir="LR"` then you can get a horizontal plot.

Example:

```
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(
    model,
    to_file="model.png",
    show_shapes=False,
    show_dtype=False,
    show_layer_names=True,
    rankdir="LR",
    expand_nested=False,
    dpi=96,
    layer_range=None,
    show_layer_activations=False,
)
```